# shard cluster doesn't seem to be dividing data based on keys on mongoDB prototype

Tags: mongodb, sharding

**Background Information**

I have the following shard cluster defined:

```
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "version" : 4,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 4,
    "currentVersion" : 5,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("547496dd009cc54d845c2ff1")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "jjrs0",  "host" : "jjrs0/mongohost1:27017" }
    {  "_id" : "jjrs1",  "host" : "jjrs1/mongohost2:27017" }
    {  "_id" : "jjrs2",  "host" : "jjrs2/mongohost3:27017" }
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "rtables",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "jjrs1" }
        rtables.widgets
            shard key: { "location" : 1, "name" : 1 }
            chunks:
                jjrs1   1
            { "location" : { "$minKey" : 1 }, "name" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "location" : { "$maxKey" : 1 }, "name" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : jjrs1 Timestamp(1, 0) 
    {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "jjrs0" }

mongos>
```

I have 3 replicasets (each with just a primary for testing purposes).
I've defined "location" as being my shard key, where location will contain values like "CAN" for "Canada" and "USA" for "United States". 
I am hoping to have a different location on different shards.

**Shard Key**

I've made what I *think it a compound key.  The location, and the name fields make up the key.  A widget's name will always be unique.

**What the Data / CSV Files Look Like**

The Canada CSV files look like this:

```
location,name,rt_id,type
canada,can-widget111,123,the best widget
canada,can-widget222,1,the next best widget
```

The USA CSV looks like:

```
location,name,rt_id,type
usa,usa-widget1,24,test widget
usa,usa-widget2,25,widget widget
```

**Problem**

Either I'm misunderstanding how the shard keys work, or I've set something up incorrectly... or maybe I'm not validating my data properly.  In any case, here's whats happening:

1. I've imported all canada records into the primary shard for the "rtables" database "jjrs1".  This is the command I ran:

> ```
>  mongoimport -h mongohost2 --port 27017 -d rtables -c widgets --type csv /tmp/canada_rtables.csv --headerline
> ```

2. I started mongo on this host.. and then check the number of records in the rtables.widgets collection, and it matches the number of records imported.  Let's say 50.
3. Then i imported all records for United States by running a similar command, like so:

> mongoimport -h mongohost2 --port 27017 -d rtables -c widgets --type
>   csv /tmp/usa_rtables.csv --headerline

4. I checked the records in the "primary" replicaset jjsr1 and it had the new records in the collection.
5. The other two databases on the other replicasets (jjrs0 and jjrs2) and empty. Infact the rtables databases on both servers are empty, as you can see below:

> jjrs2:PRIMARY> use rtables
>       switched to db rtables
>       jlrs2:PRIMARY> show databases
>       admin       (empty)
>       local       1.078GB
>       rtables  (empty)
>       jjrs2:PRIMARY>

and

```
jjrs0:PRIMARY> show databases
admin       (empty)
local       1.078GB
rtables  (empty)
test        0.078GB
jjrs0:PRIMARY>
```

**Questions**

1. Am I correct in assuming that the data will be divided in such a way where all the Canadian content will be in one replicaset and the USA data in another?
2. If so, am I testing properly?
3. If my assumption is incorrect, can you please explain how the division of data is supposed to occur based on the shard key I've defined?

I've found the following post that might be related... but I haven't been able to apply the answer to my own questions..: 
[Mongo sharding fails to split large collection between shards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681540/mongo-sharding-fails-to-split-large-collection-between-shards?rq=1)

I'm still mulling it over.

Thanks

**EDIT 1**

I'm thinking that maybe I should use a tag as a shard key? 
Maybe something like this:

```
mongos> sh.addShardTag("jjrs1", "CAN")
mongos> sh.addShardTag("jjrs1", "USA")
mongos> sh.addShardTag("jjrs0", "JPN")
mongos> sh.addShardTag("jjrs2", "IND")
mongos> sh.addShardTag("jjrs2", "TAI")
mongos> sh.addShardTag("jjrs1", "VET")
mongos> sh.status()
```

The next question would be how to then associate every record that has "can" in the location field with jjrs1...

Comment: How much data is there? The data generally won't be split between shards until there's 100's of megabytes. Your `sh.status` shows one chunk, which implies to me there's not much data.

Comment: @wdberkeley there isn't much data ... a few thousand records.  So you're saying if I start to add more,that's when I see it shard?

Comment: Yup. You need several hundred megabytes of data before you can expect to see meaningful distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

`mongoimport -h mongohost2` ...

Here is your first mistake. You are importing directly into a "regular" **mongod** host. You should have used **mongos** for imports, which holds routing logic (which chunks reside on which shard).

Also, take a look at the following:

```
chunks:
    jjrs1   1
{"location" : {"$minKey" : 1}, "name" : {"$minKey" : 1} } -->> 
{"location" : {"$maxKey" : 1}, "name" : {"$maxKey" : 1} } on : jjrs1 Timestamp(1, 0)
```

This can be read as "for every location and name values, the document should be routed to jjrs1.

This is no wonder. A chunk is a sequence of documents with a shard key within a certain range. Also, each chunk's default size is 64MB. If a document's size average is 64KB for example, you will have to insert more than 1000 documents (let's say 500+ for US and 500+ for CANADA) before the chunk will split into 2.

Then, `sh.status()` may resemble something like:

```
 chunks:
    jjrs0   0
{"location" : {"$minKey" : 1}, "name" : {"$minKey" : 1} } -->> 
{"location" : "canada", "name" : {"$maxKey" : 1} } on : jjrs0 Timestamp(1, 0)
    jjrs1   1
{"location" : {"usa" : 1}, "name" : {"$minKey" : 1} } -->> 
{"location" : {"$maxKey" : 1}, "name" : {"$maxKey" : 1} } on : jjrs1 Timestamp(1, 0)
```

> I'm thinking that maybe I should use a tag as a shard key? Maybe something like this:

Well this is not a shard key, but a mechanism to associate tags with shards. This is a step in the right direction, but not enough.

For example, using the (imaginary) `sh.status()` above, once the chunk had split into two, the **"canadian"** chunk had been migrated to `jjrs0`. This may not be the desired behavior, assuming you want to rout the **"american"** documents to `jjrs0`.

Why does it happen? Because you've missed [declaring tag ranges](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.addTagRange/). Without these the shard tags are just static cluster metadata.

You will also have to configure tag ranges as follows:

```
sh.addTagRange( "rtables.widgets", 
   { country: "usa", name: MinKey }, { country: "usa", name: MaxKey }, "USA")
sh.addTagRange( "rtables.widgets", 
   { country: "canada", name: MinKey }, { country: "canada", name: MaxKey }, "CAN")
```

To wrap it up, in order for the american documents to be on `jjrs0` shard, and Canadian to be on `jjrs1`, do the following:

1. Optionally delete all `widget` documents from jjrs1.
2. Declare the shard tags as in the edit section of your post (for sake of testing, `CAN` and `USA` are enough).
3. Declare the tag ranges as above.
4. Use a `mongos` for import.

**Comment:** for the rest of the countries - where tags had not been declared -an attempt will be made to balance the cluster, meaning chunks will be routed / migrated randomly in order to balance the number of chunks among shards.

Comment: so I have added tag ranges... but can you tell me where i can find information about how to do the import of data from mongos instead of on the specific shard?  that comment / suggestion looks promising...

Comment: It's a regular mongoimport, only via mongos. If you have mongos installed on mongohost4 (default port is same as mongod, i.e. 20717) you will run `mongoimport -h mongohost4 ...` followed by the rest of the import command. If for example the mongos process is co-located with a mongod on mongohost2 and it's default port is 28017, you will run `mongoimport -h mongohost2 --port 28017...` followed by the rest of the import command.

Comment: I have mongos installed on a separate box... one that is not hosting a shard.  so i tried to follow your first example but it's giving me an error.  Please see my latest edit.

Comment: orid, the trick was to import from the mongos machine... not from a shard like you suggested.  thanks!

Comment: Thanks. But I have mentioned mongos import: 'You are importing directly into a "regular" mongod host. You should have used mongos for imports, which holds routing logic'